# How to add columns based on the number of the fileds in the dataframe using streamlit and python

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that read a csv file and display the content as dataframe.

I need to display the column names as `text_input` by displaying them in a horizontal layout beside each other , by using `st.columns()`.

The problem is that when i run the app it crash and display the below error:

```
StreamlitAPIException: The input argument to st.columns must be either a positive integer or a list of positive numeric weights. See documentation for more information.
Traceback:

File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 1580, in <module>
    main()
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 479, in main
    cols = st.columns(ncol)
```

## code:

```
num_new_rows = st.sidebar.number_input("Add Rows",1,50)
ncol = st.session_state.df.shape[1]
    
with st.form(key='add_record_form',clear_on_submit= True):
        st.subheader("Add Record")
        cols = st.columns(ncol)
        rwdta = [
                 cols[i].text_input(st.session_state.df.columns[i]) for i in range(ncol)
                ]
```

Comment: Can you add `print(ncol)` just before `cols = st.columns(ncol)` and share the result?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the type of the file. It seems that streamlit has changed the way it assigns the type of a selected file where if it is a csv:

I changed te file type from `"application/vnd.ms-excel"` to `"text/csv"`.